# How to connect to the process running on 'localhost' that is inside of cloud9 server

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

I have a Javascript project that I work on in **cloud9 IDE online**,
and I wanted to test my code using **testem npm module**:
npmjs.org/package/testem  together with libraries like Mocha or Jasmine.

I was following [this tutorial on net tuts +](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/make-javascript-testing-fun-with-testem/)

I have installed the ***testem npm module***, but when I run it using command "**testem**" in cloud9's terminal window testem asks me to open a new tab in "**localhost:7357**"

Generally to preview workspace files in cloud9 I would go to 
https://c9.io/username/folders.../workspace/folders.../index.html

Since I am on the cloud9 server, I wanted
to know if it is possible to open this '**localhost**' link from the browser,
and if yes, how would I do it?

(I tried '**localhost**', '**127.0.0.1**', '**0.0.0.0**' ***inside cloud9's IDE***, but it did not work).

Maybe I can access it differently?

Like "username.cl9.io/workspace:PORT" ?

If not, maybe it is possible to provide a link and port to testem 
(and by any chance how would one do it ?).
I know in cloud9 you can use **process.env.IP** and **process.env.PORT** to provide to different
modules, but no idea on how to open such files later from the browser.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running a node process:
http://**workspacename.username**.c9users.io will be the link to get to it.

If you want to preview a particular file in the workspace:
https://c9users.io/**username/workspacename**/workspace/**filename.html**

### Example:

My name is bob, and my project name is mycoolproject.

*Running* node service link - http://**mycoolproject.bob**.c9users.io

*Direct file* preview link - https://c9users.io/**bob/mycoolproject**/workspace/**index.html**

Answer (score 5):

If you run testem with the host and port variables:

```
testem --host $IP -p $PORT
```

You should be able to connect from your browser by going to the root of your external server:

```
http://workspace.username.c9users.io/
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really late response, but I get the feeling that you simply just need the right hostname and you'll be in business. My method for getting C9's hostname is as follows:

If you open up a terminal and access the mysql command line by typing in

`mysql-ctl start`

followed by

`mysql-ctl cli`

which will take you to the MySQL command line interface, and then you can run this query:

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'hostname';`

It will give you back your hostname under the column *hostname* which should look something like this:

`yourUsername-yourProjectName-XXXXXXX`

where the `X`'s form a 7 digit number. You can use that as your hostname instead of *localhost* or *127.0.0.1* (which have never worked for most people and I'm not sure why people on other SO posts consistently suggest those). I have used this hostname before to sync my PHP scripts with my MySQL databases (before C9 implemented a built-in phpMyAdmin), and always had success with it.

Comment: o, nice.
I haven't tried this myself yet, but I hope I get a chance soon.
But if you had success with it, I think this is a right answer.
I will mark it as so when I get a chance to test this out.
Thanks a lot for the reply, I hope it will also help others with similar hostname issues.

Comment: Your solution inadvertently solved my problem, but in Ubuntu just type `hostname` to get the c9 hostname. In my particular case I'm using `php -S (my cloud9 hostname):8080 etc` instead of localhost and that worked. I wasted a lot of time trying to get localhost to work!

Answer (score 1):

on C9.io its simple for me.

**`Just open the file(i.e server.js or index.js or index.html) and click on preview button.`**

**WAO you are done. :)**

hope it help.

*I created an application using node + express + react and then i created a simple server.js and click the preview, it open the browser.*

Answer (score 1):

**sorry for that, you can't!**

> Available ports on a hosted Cloud9 workspace
>
> If you're developing a server application, please note that you need
>   to listen to 0.0.0.0 ($IP) and 8080 ($PORT). Listening to this port
>   will enable your app to be viewable at
>   http://-.c9users.io
>
> You can also bind to ports 8081, and 8082, which can be accessed by
>   http://-.c9users.io:8081 and
>   http://-.c9users.io:8082 respectively.
>
> Please note that 8080, 8081, and 8082 are the only available ports on
>   a hosted Cloud9 workspace.

https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application